# algorithm2e - Undefined control sequence. \end

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I don't understand why i have this error at the "\end{algorithm}" line

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish} 
\usepackage[spanish,onelanguage,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} %for psuedo code
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}

\begin{algorithm}[H] %or another one check
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \SetKwFunction{FSonIguales}{son\_iguales}
    \SetKwProg{Fn}{Funcion}{}{fin}

    \Fn{\FSonIguales{$X[1..n]$, $Y[1..n]$}}{
        \;\comment{\# Si es array vacío, devuelvo verdadero}\;
        \uIf{$X.longitud == 0$ $\&\&$ $Y.longitud == 0$}{
            \KwRet verdadero\; 
        }
        \;\comment{\# Compruebo si primeros elemento son distintos}\;
        \uElseIf{$X[1]$  $!=$  $Y[1]$}{
            \KwRet falso\;
        }
        \;\comment{\# Compruebo el resto del array}\;
        \Else{
            \KwRet son\_iguales($X[2..n]$, $Y[2..n]$)\;
        }   
    }
\end{algorithm}

Line 126 - Undefined control sequence. \end
Line 126 - Undefined control sequence. \end
Line 126 - Undefined control sequence. \end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined control sequence is `\comment`. Here is the full error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument>  \;\comment 
                       {\# Si es array vacío, devuelvo verdadero}\; \uIf {$...
l.25 \end
         {algorithm}
?
```

What can you do? Just don't use `\comment`, which is undefined. The macros for comments are `\tcp` and `\tcc`, described in section 10.3 of the manual of `algorithm2e`.